# Blazor - when open the main page without being authenticated never redirect to login page

Tags: authorization, blazor

I'm using Blazor with .net 6. In the app.razor page I have the defaults for **AutorizedRouteView** and **NotAuthorized**. It's working fine, except for main page. If does not have any authenticated, should redirect to login page, but it's always detecting the **NotAuthorized** page.

App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <Authorizing>
                    <text> Please wait, we are authorizing the user. </text>
                </Authorizing>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img src="/assets/img/restrito.png" class="rounded" alt="não encontrado">
                        <br /><br>
                        <h1 class="fw-bolder">Não possui acesso a esta página.</h1>
                    </div>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            @{
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img src="/assets/img/404.png" class="rounded" alt="não encontrado">
                    <br /><br>
                    <h1 class="fw-bolder">Página não encontrada.</h1>

                    <a href="">Retornar à página principal</a>
                </div>
            }
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

AppRouteView.cs

```
public class AppRouteView : RouteView
    {
        [Inject]
        private NavigationManager _navigationManager { get; set; }

        [Inject]
        private IAccountService _accountService { get; set; }

        protected override void Render(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            // var authorize = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(RouteData.PageType, typeof(AuthorizeAttribute)) != null;
            if (_accountService.User == null)
            {
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("account/login");
            }
            else
            {
                base.Render(builder);
            }
        }
    }
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using VidaConfortoApplication.Client.Services.Interfaces
@attribute [Authorize]
@inject IAccountService _accountService

<div class="p-4">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Olá @_accountService.User?.Name!</h1>
        <p>Está autenticado na aplicação GesSad!</p>
        <p><NavLink href="users">Gerir utilizadores</NavLink></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Login.razor page does not have any [Authorize] attriute

Comment: Where is `AppRouteView` being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle the redirect to the login page yourself, within the `<NotAuthorized>` tag. Check whether the user is Authenticated, and if not, redirect them to the login page. Here is an example:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <NotAuthorized>
        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <RedirectToLogin />
        }
        else
        {
            <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
        }
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

Note that this also handles the difference between being Authenticated and being Authorized. A user may be logged in to a site (authenticated), without having permissions to access certain resources (authorized).

In your `<RedirectToLogin />` component, just redirect the user in `OnInitialized()` or `OnInitializedAsync()`. Here is a simple example:

```
@inject NavigationManager _nav

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _nav.NavigateTo("/account/login");
    }
}
```

If you want the user to be returned to the page they initially tried to enter, get the target uri before redirecting to login, and pass it as a query parameter to the login page (to handle the redirection after logging in). Then, the `<RedirectToLogin />` component could look like this:

```
@inject NavigationManager _nav

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var path = _nav.ToBaseRelativePath(_nav.Uri);
        _nav.NavigateTo($"/account/login?returnUrl={path}");
    }
}
```